# delete row in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, sql

im tring to delete **first row** in phpmyadmin but i have problem. i dont get any SQL error.

PHP codes

```
                           
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    echo "deleted";
    $delete = $_POST['delete'];
    $SQL = $odb -> prepare("DELETE FROM `accounts_free`LIMIT 1");
    $SQL -> execute(array($delete));
    $notify = success('Account has been successfully deleted');
}
```

html

```
<form method="post">
<button name="delete" value="test" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</form>
```

another button

```
<form method="post">
<button name="delete" class="btn btn-hero-success js-click-ripple-enabled" type="submit" data-toggle="click-ripple" style="margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index: 1;">test</button>
</form>
```

i didnt find any solutions.
im not sure whats wrong. can you help me?

in different page this codes are working
php

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $delete = $_POST['delete'];
    $SQL = $odb -> prepare("DELETE FROM `accounts_free` WHERE `id` = ?");
    $SQL -> execute(array($delete));
    $notify = success('Account has been successfully deleted');
}
```

html

```
 <button name="delete" value="<?=$rAccount['id']?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
```

Comment: You forgot the WHERE clause and the parameter placeholder in your query. Switch on error reporting / logging - you likely have an error about the number of parameters not matching the number of placeholders

Comment: I am pretty sure that you do get an error in your http server's error log file. Because your php syntax is invalid. Example: it should be `$odb->prepare(...`, not `$odb -> prepare(...` ... Also you need to place a blank inside ``accounts_free`LIMIT`. And you certainly want to qualify _which_ row you want to delete...

Comment: now page perma refresh

Comment: You mean it refreshes endlessly? That's probably a separate issue caused by some other code you haven't shown here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $SQLSelect = $odb->query("DELETE FROM `accounts_free` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1");
    
}

?>
```

Thats worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems to me that this is not PhpMyAdmin but your own PHP code. Second, as @ADyson and @arkascha suggested, you will want to specify which row to delete possibly using the row primary key. For example, you can add this inside your `<form>` tags:

```
<input type="hidden" name="accounts_free_id" value="ACCOUT_FREE_ID_TO_DELETE">
```

And inside your `if`:

```
//space removed as @arkascha suggested
$SQL = $odb->prepare("DELETE FROM `accounts_free` WHERE `id`='.$_POST['accounts_free_id'].'");
```

In this example I suppose the identifier of `accounts_free` table is `id`. This is only to give you the idea: remember that every input that arrives from the outside has to be checked to avoid SQL Injection or other kinds of attack attempts.

Comment: thank you for your suggest. but in different page this codes are working
php
```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $delete = $_POST['delete'];
    $SQL = $odb -> prepare("DELETE FROM `accounts_free` WHERE `id` = ?");
    $SQL -> execute(array($delete));
    $notify = success('Account has been successfully deleted');
}
```
html
```
 <button name="delete" value="<?=$rAccount['id']?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>

```

Comment: You have to remove the spaces before and after the arrow ```->```.